# turn negative bytes in byte array to positive by adding 256 - java

Tags: java, arrays, char, bytebuffer

I have a byte array:

```
byte[] b = [108, 108, -17, 65] // Arrays.toString(b)
```

and I want to turn negatives into negatives +256, like: -17 + 256 = 239
so that I have:

```
b = [108, 108, 239, 65]
```

I tried:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   if (b[i] < 0){
      int n = (b[i] + 256);
      byte b1 = (byte) (b[i] + 256);

      buffer.position(i);
      buffer.put(i, (byte) (n & 0xFF));
   }
}
```

but nothing changes.
I would be very thankful for any advices

Comment: `byte` is a signed 8-bit value, so it can't represent 239.

Comment: There is no difference at a bit level. Just write the signed negative bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't represent anything over 127 as a positive valued byte. So you would have to have an array of `ints` to `show` the value like you want.  I use the word `show` because it is important to realize that this is just a representation of the actual value for use by humans.  It has no bearing on the intrinsic nature of the value.

```
byte b = 239;
System.out.println(b);
```

Prints

```
-17
```

I suspect you would want the unsigned value which can be printed like so.

```
byte b = -17;
System.out.println(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b));
```

Prints

```
239
```